# Python for loop to concatenate dataframes

Tags: list, dataframe, for-loop, python-requests

I have 600 dataframes that need to be concatenated (rows appended). dt1, dt2, dt3 ... dt600.

Is there an easy way to do that with a for loop? Create a list and use pd.concat, but how do I make a list of dts.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you generating 600 dataframes, in a loop or seperate?

Comment: 600 different dataframes that have different coefficients and variables but same columns - I wanted to merge them in one big dataframe. 
My temporary solution is to do it in excel and then convert the list to text + use pd.concat

I wanted to do it in a for loop just like you can do in SAS but I was unsuccessful.